# Parsing out address data that may not be in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am currently working on a project wherein the client needs to have a single field, in this case a city state and zip field split into 3 separate fields in a view. I did find code which does this well, however the problem I am running into is, that the city state and zip data is not always in the same column. Sometimes it is in the shp_to_addr_2 column, and sometimes it is in the shp_to_addr_3 column.

The code ends up throwing a parameter error because it sometimes ends up with a null value passed to it. I have tried using a variable to catch the column with the data in it, but still end up with this pesky error. Here is the code I have set up as a stored procedure, with the error message. What am I doing wrong?

```
USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USER_SP_VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2]

@address VARCHAR(50) = NULL

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
  UPDATE VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2
  SET @address = shp_to_addr_3

  IF @address IS NULL
    SELECT ord_no, cust_no, ord_dat, shp_to_nam, shp_to_addr_1, shp_to_addr_2, shp_to_addr_3, ord_typ,
    (LEFT(shp_to_addr_2, CHARINDEX(',', shp_to_addr_2) - 1)) AS City, LEFT(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(shp_to_addr_2, 
    CHARINDEX(',', shp_to_addr_2) + 1, 4)), 2) AS ST, RIGHT(RTRIM(shp_to_addr_2), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE
    (RTRIM(shp_to_addr_2))) - 1) AS Zip
    FROM VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2

  ELSE IF @address IS NOT NULL

    SELECT ord_no, cust_no, ord_dat, shp_to_nam, shp_to_addr_1, shp_to_addr_2, shp_to_addr_3, ord_typ,
    (LEFT(shp_to_addr_3, CHARINDEX(',', shp_to_addr_3) - 1)) AS City, LEFT(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(shp_to_addr_3, 
    CHARINDEX(',', shp_to_addr_3) + 1, 4)), 2) AS ST, RIGHT(RTRIM(shp_to_addr_3), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE
    (RTRIM(shp_to_addr_3))) - 1) AS Zip
    FROM VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2
END
```

The procedure compiles, but when executed I get this:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Procedure USER_SP_VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2, Line 13
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: you will need to debug your code.First try to understand  what paramters left /Right ,substring takes.Then check your code to see if you passing any invalid parameter,its hard to debug for us as well ,since there is no actual data to test

Comment: I would recommend using `select` instead of `update` when getting data into variables. Using update makes it more confusing since you're not actually updating the table.

Comment: This view code works when data in shp_to_addr_3, but when in the other column shp_to_addr_2, it errors.

SELECT ord_no, cust_no, ord_dat, shp_to_nam, shp_to_addr_1, shp_to_addr_2, shp_to_addr_3, ord_typ,
(LEFT(shp_to_addr_3, CHARINDEX(',', shp_to_addr_3) - 1)) AS City, LEFT(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(shp_to_addr_3, 
CHARINDEX(',', shp_to_addr_3) + 1, 4)), 2) AS ST, RIGHT(RTRIM(shp_to_addr_3), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE
(RTRIM(shp_to_addr_3))) - 1) AS Zip
FROM VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2

Answer (score 0):

You're just fetching the last row that happens to come from the table `VI_USER_UPS_TRACK_2` into the variable `@address` and based on that you go to different path. I would assume there's a lot more rows in your table, so your logic doesn't work at all.

You need to write a case statement that checks the individual rows you're handling and takes the data based on that.

Also, `@address` is the input parameter of the procedure, but you overwrite the value in the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: I tried to do this in the original view code, I got that same error message. Example here:

Comment: Where's the example? The code you posted in comments in the question is totally wrong. You need a case statement for deciding from what address field to take the data from.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am still learning the advanced side of T-SQL, and my coworker who is a bit more experienced than me got the view to work with the Case Select. I don't know why the example I pasted in did not show up. I will post the working code in the Answers option in case someone else needs to work on a project that is similar.